# How to understand the `callable` in the right way?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, callable, packaged-task

As per the [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable), which says:

> A Callable type is a type for which the INVOKE operation (used by,
> e.g., std::function, std::bind, and std::thread::thread) is
> applicable. This operation may be performed explicitly using the
> library function std::invoke. (since C++17)
>
> Requirements
>
> The type T
> satisfies Callable if Given f,
> an object of type T ArgTypes,
> suitable list of argument types R,
>
> expressions must be valid:
>
> std::declval()...)  the expression is well-formed in
> unevaluated contextExpression Requirements INVOKE(f,suitable return type The following

**Question 1**:

If I understand correctly, given `void foo(int) {}`, `std::function(foo)` is not callable, whereas `std::function(foo, 1)` is callable. Am I right?

**Question 2**:
What confuses me is the statement below.

As per the document, which says[emphasis mine]:

> The class template **std::packaged_task wraps any Callable target**
> (function, lambda expression, bind expression, or another function
> object) so that it can be invoked asynchronously. Its return value or
> exception thrown is stored in a shared state which can be accessed
> through std::future objects.

As you see that the class template std::packaged_task wraps any **Callable target**, and `std::function{foo}` is not callable, but `std::packged_task<void(int)> task{f};` compiles.

Comment: `void foo(int) {}`, `std::function(foo)` are both Callable.

Comment: `std::function(foo, 1)` is ill-formed, it takes 0 or 1 arguments in the constructor in C++17 (when class template argument deduction is available)

Answer (score 3):

If one wants to be a successful professional, they do not stop reading [the article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) on the introduction. If they continue reading the article and the referenced articles, they find all answers there.

Your first question is answered directly on that page:

- otherwise, `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is equivalent to `f(t1, t2, ..., tN)` (that is, f is a [FunctionObject](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FunctionObject)).

Opening the reference:

> A **FunctionObject** type is the type of an object that can be used on the left of the function call operator.

Therefore, `void foo(int) {}` is callable. The both `std::function(foo)` and `std::function(foo, 1)`  will not compile. I guess you mean `std::function f(foo)`, or `std::function f{foo}`, or `std::function<void(int)> f(foo)`, the both are obviously callable, and I guess you confused `std::bind(foo, 1)` with `std::function(foo, 1)`, that is also callable.

You know now, why `std::packged_task<void(int)> task{f};` is compiled - because `f` is callable as it is figured out above.